Room database dependencies in Android Studio Koala
I want to add libraries to be able to work on room databases, but I don't know which one to insert.
I am working on Android Studio Koala SDK 34 and Gradle KTS, I use Java as language.
Can someone help me?


I tried adding dependencies from the FILE->PROJECT STRUCTURE menu.But there are many items and I don't know which one to choose


You're using obsolete libraries: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room

Thank you very much,Martin, for the quick response, I inserted room.guava, as you can see in the last photo but not if alone is enough to make roomdatabase work.

thank you very much it work with   val room_version = "2.6.1"
// added for room
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
